# Start a new thread from the constructor of a QMainWindow in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, qtgui, qtcore

I have the `MainWindow` class. In the constructor of this class I want to start a new thread that will do some work. But I get this error:

> Assert failure in QWidget: "Widgets must be created in the GUI thread."

In this new thread I am not creating any widgets. This is what I have tried so far. Could someone help me on solving this problem? In don't have experience with signals and slots and I will really appreciate some advises.

**newThread.h**

```
#ifndef NEWTHREAD_H
#define NEWTHREAD_H
#include <QThread>
#include "mainwindow.h"

class NewThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit NewThread(QObject *parent = 0);
signals:    
public slots:
protected:
    void run();
};

#endif // NEWTHREAD_H
```

**newThread.cpp**

```
#include "newthread.h"
NewThread::NewThread(QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent) { }

void NewThread::run(){
    MainWindow m;
    m.updateInBackground();
}
```

**MainWindow.cpp**

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QStringList applications, QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
    ReadFromRegistry read;
    this->setFixedSize(435,280);
    ui->setupUi(this);
    appsNames = applications;
    this->apps = read.getApplicationsFromRegistry(appsNames);
    ui->updateInBackgroundCkb->setChecked(false);
    //read from settings.xml the time interval
    QString time = RWXml::readSettingsFile();
    if(time.compare("-1") != 0){
       NewThread th;
       while(true){
            th.start();
            th.sleep(time.toLong(0,10));
       }    
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);    

    QStringList apps;
    QString app = "AppTest1";
    apps.append(app);
    app = "AppTest2";
    apps.append(app);
    app = "AppTest3";
    apps.append(app);    

    MainWindow w(apps);
    w.create();
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

I instantiate the `MainWindow` in main. But i need to access the method from `MainWindow` in the run method of the `NewThread`. That's why it is instantiated in the `NewThread`.

**EDIT:**

```
void MainWindow::updateInBackground(){
ClientSocket client;
for(Application ap : getApps()){

    QString currentVersion = ap.getAppVersion();
    QString appCode = ap.getAppCode();
    QString appSerial = ap.getAppSerialNo();
    client.connect();

    QString message = "2//" + currentVersion + "//"  + appCode + "//"+ appSerial;

    //send message to the server
    client.sendMessage(message);
    //receiver message from the server
    QString received = client.receiveMessage();
    //check if the current version is the last one
    if(received.compare("0") != 0){
        //if is not the last one, set the new version            
        ap.setAppVersion(received);
        //set the update date           
        ap.setCurrentDate();
        //write in windows registry
        WriteInRegistry::writeRegistry(ap);
        //update the xml file containg the updates of this application           
        updateXMLFile(ap);
    }
}
//read from registry
ReadFromRegistry read;
//populate the grid from the MainWindow with the new data
populateTable(read.getApplicationsFromRegistry(getAppsNames()));
client.closeConnection();
}
```

Comment: You *are* creating a GUI widget in something other than the GUI thread - the very first line of `NewThread::run()` (`MainWindow m;`) constructs a new widget in that thread.

Comment: @AndrewMedico I have to access that method from MainWindow somehow. I tried to make that method static but couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about what you're trying to do in the bigger picture? You might not even need a thread at all - it looks like maybe you're just periodically refreshing some settings and you could that with a timer connected to a slot on your MainWindow (assuming the settings re-read doesn't take long enough to noticeably block the GUI).

Comment: You shouldn't be instantiating new copies of your MainWindow from the thread. If you actually need to call methods on the MainWindow from the thread, you should use Qt's signals and slots system to perform cross-thread calls (the linked tutorial shows how).

Comment: @AndrewMedico I added the method updateInBackground so you can have a look.

Comment: Based on your `updateInBackground` function, you're going to have to rework your code. Given that it does network communications, calling it from a timer in the main thread could cause excessive UI blocking. I'm assuming that the `populateTable` function it calls does update a widget, and this is not allowed from anything other than the main thread. You'll need to split the code up so that the data-retrieval is done by the background thread which emits a signal (using a queued / non-blocking connection) to a slot on the MainWindow to do the GUI updates.

Comment: I experienced the timer and yes, it causes UI blocking. Right now i am trying to split the code to can use a background thread. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue with your code is that you create the mainwindow and the qt application in different threads. The main window seems to be created in your "new thread", whereas the qt application is not.

You also seem to have a circular dependency between the mainwindow constructor and the run method of the thread.

You would need to move the mainwindow creation into your main.cpp which is also a logical place for it.

That being said, please do take a look at the url below and all the references in the post for getting some further thoughts.

[How to Use QThread in the Right Way (Part 1)](http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-1/)

[How to Use QThread in the Right Way (Part 2)](http://blog.debao.me/2013/08/how-to-use-qthread-in-the-right-way-part-2/)

Comment: I added the main.cpp class in my question. So at this moment the only problem is to figure out how to call that method from the MainWindow without creating a new object.